# Get Page URL In Order To Use It To Include

Tags: php, include

So I made a script so that I can just use includes to get my header, pages, and then footer. And if a file doesnt exist a 404. That all works. Now my issue is how I'm supposed to get the end of the url being the page. For example,

I want to make it so that when someone goes to example.com/home/test, it will automatically just include test.php for example.

Moral of the story. How to some how get the page name. And then use it to "mask" the end of the page so that I don't need to have every URL being something.com/home/?p=home

Heres my code so far.

```
<?php 
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/home/lib/php/_dc.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/home/lib/php/_home_fns.php');

$script   = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; //This returns /home/index.php for example =/
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/home/default/header.php');
if($_GET["p"] == 'home' || !isset($_GET["p"])) {
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/home/pages/home.php');
} else if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/home/pages/'.$_GET["p"].'.php'))      {
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/home/pages/'.$_GET["p"].'.php');    
} else {
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/home/default/404.php'); 
}
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/home/default/footer.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP by itself wouldn't be the best choice here unless you want your website littered with empty "redirect" PHP files. I would recommend looking into the Apache server's `mod_rewrite` module. Here are a [couple](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) of [guides](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) to get you started. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to have an index.php file inside the /home/whatever folder. Then use  something like $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and extract the name if you want to automate it, or since you are already writing the file yourself, hardcode it into it.

That however looks plain wrong, you should probably look into mod-rewrite if you are up to creating a more complex/serious app.

I would also recommend cakePHP framework that has the whole path-to-controller thing worked out.